# How to mock python dict __str__ method?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a method which takes as a parameter a dict which needs to contain certain entries. For example, I may expect a `type` key in the dict whose value needs to be one of `['typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC']`. If a key is missing, I have the method throw an exception, `SpecFormatException`. The exception message should read something like `'type' entry is missing in spec dict: {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': [1, 2, 3]}`.

I am writing a test to verify that the exception is being thrown with the correct error message, but since the output of the `dict.__str__()` method is nondeterministic, my test is flaky. I thought that if I could patch the `dict.__str__()` method to output something like "YES I AM YOUR DICTIONARY" then I could fix the flakiness, but when I try to patch my test with:

```
import mock
import my_verifier

@mock.patch('my_verifier.dict')
def testErrorMessage(this, dict_str):
  dict_str.return_value = 'YES I AM YOUR DICTIONARY'
  ...
```

I get the error message "my_verifier.py does not have the attribute 'dict'" when trying to run my test.

I assume mocking the `__str__` method is the right approach here, but how exactly do I do it?

Comment: Could you change the actual implementation of the exception so that it uses a predictable order, eg by sorting alphabetically?

Comment: Is writing a deterministic `dict2str(dct)` function an option?

Comment: The message string shouldn't contain any information that needs to be parsed. If it's that important, add an attribute to the custom exception that provides it directly. The fact that a `SpecFormatException` is raised already tells you what you will see in the message: that the `dict` did not have `type` as a key.

Comment: @DanielRoseman,  I could do that, but it feels hacky to alter the functionality of my method to serve the purposes of the test.

Comment: Really, you don't care what the exact message is, just that it is the concatenation of `"'type' entry is missing in spec dict: "` and `str(d)` for the appropriate `d`.

Comment: @Catherine That's not hacky; it's writing testable code.

Comment: @chepner Even if I don't include the contents of the dict in this error message, eventually I will need to surface this to the user (possibly as a warning when they run the script) and I will want to test that the message contains the dict at that point.

Comment: And it will, as long as you verify that `str(d)` was called. It's not your test's job to verify that `str(d)` returns any particular string.

Comment: @chepner Fair enough.

Comment: @chepner Still, with any other method, I could and often would mock the return value precisely because it's not my test's job to verify that `str(d)` returns any particular string. Is there any reason why this is a bad approach in this case?

Comment: I'm assuming you instantiate the exception with something like `SpecFormatException(d)`, where `d` is the `dict` in question. To test the message being set, `d` doesn't actually have to be a `dict`, just something that has a `__str__` method.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: @fferi I have 5K+ rep and have been a member for nearly 7 years. Where did you get the idea that I am new here? Also you might note that none of the answers actually answer the question that I asked--which is how to mock the python builtin dictionary's `__str__` method.

Answer (score 1):

How specific does your test for the error message need to be? Could you maybe just assert that some part of what you expect is in there, such as:

```
import pytest

def test_my_method_error_message():
    offending_key = 'test'
    data = {offending_key: 'whatever'}
    with pytest.raises(SpecFormatException) as excinfo:
        my_method(data)
        assert data in str(excinfo.value)
```

Obviously, you might need to test other parts of the message as well. Testing for the EXACT string may or not be what you want to do, as that message might change. If you need to go down that route, I would suggest maybe storing the strings (or string templates) somewhere that can be accessed by everything, so that your test can make it's assertion based on a class variable or configuration parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If replacing the built-in `dict.__str__` method with a custom dict2str function is an option, here's one that sorts keys alphabetically:

```
def det_str(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return '{{{}}}'.format(', '.join('{!r}: {}'.format(k, det_str(v)) for k, v in sorted(x.items())))
    else:
        return str(x)
```

```
>>> det_str({'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': -1})
"{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': -1}"
>>> det_str({'c': -1, 'a': 1, 'b': 0})
"{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': -1}"
```

works also recursively:

```
>>> det_str({'b': 0, 'a': 1, 'c': -1, 'd': {'z': 10, 'x': 20, 'y': -30}})
"{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': -1, 'd': {'x': 20, 'y': -30, 'z': 10}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you pass a dictionary as an argument when you raise the exception, something like

```
d = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': [1, 2, 3]}
if not d.get('type') in ['typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC']:
    raise SpecFormatException(d)
```

The first test will focus solely on the exception itself, which means the argument doesn't really matter, as long as it is something that has a `__str__` method:

```
def testExceptionMessage(self):
    d = mock.MagicMock()
    exc = SpecFormatException(d)
    observed = str(exc)
    self.assertEqual(observed,
                     "'type' entry is missing in spec dict: {}".format(d)
```

If you check the value of `d.__str__.called` before and after calling `str(exc)`, you should see the value change from `False` to `True`, verifying that `SpecFormatException` does indeed use the argument's `__str__` method to create the value of `observed`.

The second test focuses on the exception being raised as expected. You don't really need to check what its message is, because 1) you've already tested that elsewhere and 2) the message doesn't really contain any information that you can't glean from the `dict` instance itself and the fact that `SpecFormatException` is, indeed, raised.

```
def testRaiseException(self):
    with self.assertRaises(SpecFormatException):
        # code that should cause SpecFormatException be raised
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but I had the same difficulty and couldn't find a working answer. I ended up using `unittest.mock.MagicMock` to mock the `__str__` output of an object's function. `MagicMock` is [designed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#magic-methods) to mock Python's magic functions, such as `__str__`.

You shouldn't need to use anything like `SpecFormatException` for the test itself. You can use `mock.patch` as a context manager -- for your code, this would look like:

```
import my_verifier
import unittest.mock


def test_my_method_error_message():
    with mock.patch("my_verifier.dict", mock.MagicMock()) as mock_dict:
        mock_dict.__str__.return_value = "YES I AM YOUR DICTIONARY"
        assert str(mock_dict) == "YES I AM YOUR DICTIONARY"

        # ...other tests that rely on a mocked instance of my_verifier.dict...

    # ...other tests that don't rely on a mocked instance of my_verifier.dict...
```

Assuming that `my_verifier` has a `dict` object/method, this allows you to control the output of printing `my_verifier.dict` for one or more tests, but without fully replacing `my_verifier.dict` with a mock object.

You can also mock other (magic) functions of `my_verifier.dict` inside the same context, and have any other tests reside outside the context.

The [patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) method may also be of use.